# getServletContext.getRealPath() is not working?

Tags: java, servlets

`getServletContext.getRealPath("string")` is throwing a null pointer exception. How can I use it to get the real path?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{

    String fileName="xyz.pdf";    
    ServletOutputStream stream=null;    
    BufferedInputStream buf=null;    
    try    
    {

        stream=res.getOutputStream();    
        String s1=getServletContext().getRealPath("pdfFiles/xyz.pdf");    
        File doc=new File(s1);    
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");    
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);    
        res.setContentLength((int)doc.length());    
        FileInputStream input=new FileInputStream(doc);    
        buf=new BufferedInputStream(input);    
        int readBytes=0;

        while((readBytes=buf.read())!=-1)    
            stream.write(readBytes);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}

}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: There's a **huge** difference between the statement *"getServletContext().getRealPath("string") throws NullPointerException"* and the statement *"getServletContext().getRealPath("string") returns null"*. Are you absolutely positive that the initial statement is true? Don't you actually mean to say the second statement?

Answer (score 2):

You've overridden `GenericServlet.init(ServletContext context)` but you haven't called `super(context);` from within it. So when you call `GenericServlet.getServletContext(),` it doesn't know where the context is, so it returns `null.`

NB your `readBytes` variable is misnamed. It will contain a single byte.

Comment: i have overridden HttpServlet class's doGet() method and not the GenericServlet class.

Comment: HttpServlet doesn't provide an init() method. It comes from GenericServlet. The symptoms you describe are consistent with you having overridden it in the way I described.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
String s1= req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("pdfFiles/xyz.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the server is Websphere, do the following:

->open admin console 
->applications->websphere enterprise applications 
-> select your deployed project (make sure its stopped)
->select 'class loading and update detection'
->in the WAR class loader policy, select 'single class loader for application'
->start the application

done.